# SQL Server - Date of newly inserted column in a table

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

As part of my project, new columns are introduced in many tables. I wanted to find out the date in which this columns are introduced. Is there a way I can query the date of insertion of all the columns in a specific table in Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.04.

Comment: Just to clarify, your title refers to SQL Server, yet you accept an answer that is based on an Oracle's data dictionary.  If you are in fact using SQL Server, would you not be querying SQL Server data dictionary objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the last_ddl_time object from the dba_objects table.